# Python behave encoding error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characte

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, encode, python-behave

I'm getting an encoding error when my behave feature test runs into a certain input from a serial port (i think it's double quotes). While the error plainly says that the 'latin-1' codec can't encode the input, and that 'utf-8' should be the correct codec, i'm not sure where to correctly make that change.

This is the current code where I encode() the data to be sent to my device:

```
    def send_cmd(self, cmd_to_send):
        time.sleep(.2)
        clean_cmd_to_send = "\r\r" + cmd_to_send + "\r"
        self.ser.reset_output_buffer()
        self.ser.reset_input_buffer()  # reset all io buffer in case of any built up
        self.ser.write(clean_cmd_to_send.encode('UTF-8', 'ignore'))
        self.ser.flush()  # wait for all data to be written before proceed with code

    def read_output(self):
        line = self.ser.readline()
        converted_line = line.decode("UTF-8", "replace").replace('\n', '')
        return converted_line
```

This is the error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError while writing error message: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 3170: ordinal not in range(256)
Exception UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 3170: ordinal not in range(256)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/bin/behave", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/behave/__main__.py", line 183, in main
    return run_behave(config)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/behave/__main__.py", line 127, in run_behave
    failed = runner.run()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 804, in run
    return self.run_with_paths()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 824, in run_with_paths
    return self.run_model()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 626, in run_model
    failed = feature.run(self)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 321, in run
    failed = scenario.run(runner)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 711, in run
    if not step.run(runner):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 1379, in run
    formatter.result(self)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/behave/formatter/plain.py", line 108, in result
    self.stream.write(u"%s\n%s\n" % (status_text, step.error_message))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 3170: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Comment: The unicode character in this case is `“ ”` . You could add some code to check and delete or skip if it is encountered?